# What proxy_pass protocols are there?

Tags: nginx

With `proxy_pass` in nginx I can use either:

```
proxy_pass http://backend;
proxy_pass https://backend;
```

the question is: What protocols can I use? In particular I'd like to use HTTP-2 over cleartext (h2c). Is this possible? Is there a list of protocols I can use with `proxy_pass`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only http and https are permitted, as specified [in the docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass). Nginx does not support http2 when acting as a proxy.

Instead, you can use [nghttp2](https://nghttp2.org/documentation/nghttpx.1.html) which does support http2 over cleartext (with the option `proto=ht` to the `--backend` argument).

Answer (score 2):

According to [the source](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/60a6551e1f28337f7b358719fe46d4c91409dbf3/src/http/modules/ngx_http_proxy_module.c#L3657-L3677) it only allows `http` and `https` protocols.